# Unable to start debugging | Visual studio 2015

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I've recently reinstalled win 10 on my pc (so the system is clean now) and when i try to start my asp project even the default one with or without debugging the following error appears -

> Unable to start debugging. Operation not supported. Unknown error:
>   0x80070057

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PA7nN.png).
I tried to reinstall visual studio 2015 community update 3, IIS (Program and feature option) and IIS Express. Nothing helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. A solution to this problem was very odd. In visual studio i created  a new asp core template project and ran it. As usual i got an error message but this time something like iis cant connect to the local machine due to naming conflict. In system properties [my computer description field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjGBA.png)  was exactly like the computer name. So i cleared it. The problem gone.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was visual studio community 2017. 
The web project was set to launch the web app with the internal browser.

Once I started the project in any other standard browsers (Chrome, Internet Explorer, Firefox, etc.) I could run the app and debug.

Hope this can be of help to someone!

Answer (score 0):

I almost tore my hair out trying to figure what was wrong - cleaned project, rebooted, cleaned out user folder, deleted virtual directory in IIS - nothing worked.

Turned out in my case it was some misspelled nodes in the web.config file.

Specifically I had:

```
<system.webServer>
    ..
    <httpprotocol>
      <customheaders>
```

instead of:

```
<system.webServer>
    ..
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
```

Fixed that and problem solved.

Also, had to remove the following (content-type) otherwise the error returned. Not sure if it was a valid setting anyway...

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    ..
    <add name="Content-Type" value="application/json"/>
```